# How to Use Column Name for Datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using DataGridView with 5 Column AS

```
SrNo   Name   Address  City  Country
```

Whenever i am retrieving Data From Data Grid View i Use Following Code :

```
SomeoneName =  MYdataGrid[1,1].Value ;
```

I have one problem with above code that if i add any Column so in entire program i should be re arrange the column no.s for example if I add FirstName Column before name Column then

```
SomeoneName =  MYdataGrid[1,1].Value ;
```

code will change as

```
SomeoneName =  MYdataGrid[2,1].Value ;
```

My Question is there is any way to rearrange colomn nos. Automatically...

Comment: I'm not sure, but see if works `MydataGrid.rows[0].Cells[ColumnName].Value;`

Comment: Your Answer is also Correct but Code goes Lengthily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you Assassin DataGridView Columns then give column Name Same As your Column Header like

```
_SrNo   _Name   _Address  _City  _Country
```

and whenever want to use datagridview value use

```
SomeoneName =  MYdataGrid[_Name.Index,1].Value ;
```

so whenever how many columns you add it will rearrange Automatically.
Hope This Will Help